# iOS Swift: TableView Data Source without using RxCocoa

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource, rx-swift

Evening, in my application I do not want to use RxCocoa and I'm trying to conforming to tableview data source and delegate but I'm having some issues.

I can't find any guide without using RxCocoa or RxDataSource.

In my ViewModel in have a `lazy computed var myData: Observable<[MyData]>` and I don't know how to get the number of rows.

I was thinking to convert the observable to a Bheaviour Subject and then get the value but I really don't know which is the best prating to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class that conforms to UITableViewDataSource and also conforms to Observer. A quick and dirty version would look something like this:

```
class DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, ObserverType {
    init(tableView: UITableView) {
        self.tableView = tableView
        super.init()
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func on(_ event: Event<[MyData]>) {
        switch event {
        case .next(let newData):
            data = newData
            tableView.reloadData()
        case .error(let error):
            print("there was an error: \(error)")
        case .completed:
            data = []
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = data[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        // configure cell with item
        return cell
    }

    let tableView: UITableView
    var data: [MyData] = []
}
```

Make an instance of this class as a property of your view controller.
Bind your `myData` to it like:

```
self.myDataSource = DataSource(tableView: self.tableView)
self.myData
    .bind(to: self.myDataSource)
    .disposed(by: self.bag)
```

(I put all the `self`s in the above to make things explicit.)

You could refine this to the point that you effectively re-implement RxCoca's data source, but what's the point in that?

Comment: I'm afraid to get away too much from apple standard pattern and to write code that just few understands.. So you think I should use rxCocoa and maybe rxDataSource?

Comment: That's up to your team/boss, not me. I'm just saying that if you aren't going to use RxCocoa then it would be silly to go through the effort to re-implement it. The above is not a re-implementation, it's a one off class that is only suitable for a specific purpose.

Comment: thank you, I was just curious about your personal opinion

Comment: Personally, I'm all in. I think reactive approaches to programming are the future. Thirty years ago, I jumped onboard the OO bandwagon when lots of people were still thinking it was a fad. I see Reactive programming as the next big paradigm shift. IMHO, twenty years from now, everything is going to be reactive.